# Finding remote desktop enabled computers in network

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

I would like to know is there a way to search network for computers that remote desktop enabled.
Could you point me to a direction? I searched on the google but couldn't find anything useful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [nmap](https://nmap.org/book/inst-windows.html) to scan the IP range for the default Remote Desktop port (3389).

Your command would look something like this: `nmap –p 3389 192.168.0.0/24`
You should replace the IP range with your own, [Here is a tool](https://www.ipaddressguide.com/cidr) to check if you have the right one